# python how to efficiently cycle through few elements in a list

Tags: python, string, list, replace

I have a very long list in wich I would like to replace strings. I have made a simplified example below to illustrate my problem.

```
my_list = ['a7_1_1', 'a7_2_1', 'a7_3_1','a7_1_2', 'a7_2_2', 'a7_3_2','a7_1_3', 'a7_2_3', 'a7_3_3']


Out[12]:
['a7_1_1',
 'a7_2_1',
 'a7_3_1',
 'a7_1_2',
 'a7_2_2',
 'a7_3_2',
 'a7_1_3',
 'a7_2_3',
 'a7_3_3'
```

I would like to replace the strings with a suffix added to the first 3 strings so the final list should look like:

```
my_new_list = ['a7_1_1', 'a7_2_1', 'a7_3_1','a7_1_1.1', 'a7_2_1.1', 'a7_3_1.1','a7_1_1.2', 'a7_2_1.2', 'a7_3_1.2']


Out[15]:
['a7_1_1',
 'a7_2_1',
 'a7_3_1',
 'a7_1_1.1',
 'a7_2_1.1',
 'a7_3_1.1',
 'a7_1_1.2',
 'a7_2_1.2',
 'a7_3_1.2']
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: I would suggest re-wording the question to make it more general (and avoid down-voting, I suppose). Something in the lines: how to efficiently cycle through few elements in a list...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using itertools.cycle() function**

```
import itertools as it           #1

def cycle_first_n(lst, n):
    """ cycles through first n elements of the list """
    c = it.cycle(lst[:n])        #2
    for idx in xrange(len(lst)): #3
        sfx = idx / n
        yield c.next() + ('.' + str(sfx) if sfx > 0 else '')  #4
```

1. itertools is a library for creating iterators for
   efficient looping
2. creates an iterator to cycles through a slice of n elements of
   the list
3. use xrange rather than range to avoid creating a presumably long
   list in memory (see the question)
4. yield means we are creating a generator. Again to avoid creating a
   long list in memory

How to use the function

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
for o in cycle_first_n(lst, 3):
    print o,
```

Output

```
a b c a.1 b.1 c.1 a.2 b.2
```

Comment: Close... I would like to keep the first 3 stroings as they are and the rest to be a copy of those and a suffix added. So keep a7_1_1, a7_2_1 and a7_3_1 as they are. In your solution only a7_1_1 is in the new list...

Comment: Strange, I get the output ['a7_1_1', 'a7_2_1.1', 'a7_3_1.1', 'a7_1_1.1', 'a7_2_1.2', 'a7_3_1.2', 'a7_1_1.2', 'a7_2_1.3', 'a7_3_1.3']. I have used your data..

Comment: I'm not so experienced with python. I got the error message SyntaxError: 'return' outside function. Could you please instruct me how to get the code running..

Comment: Just indentation problems...the code works fine!!! Thank you so much, you really helped me!!

Comment: You are welcome! I removed my other comments as they no longer apply. Let me know if you need any explanations of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very clear with what you mean. Check if you want to do this:

```
>>> my_list = ['a7_1_1', 'a7_2_1', 'a7_3_1','a7_1_2', 'a7_2_2', 'a7_3_2','a7_1_3', 'a7_2_3', 'a7_3_3']
>>> my_new_list = sum([[x, x+'.1', x+'.2'] for x in my_list[:3]], [])
>>> print(my_new_list)
['a7_1_1', 'a7_1_1.1', 'a7_1_1.2', 'a7_2_1', 'a7_2_1.1', 'a7_2_1.2', 'a7_3_1', 'a7_3_1.1', 'a7_3_1.2']
```

Comment: Yes, that is the output that I'm looking for. However I could not get your code to work. I had a error message: TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type